# !important css is not overriding the property in firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

it works fine in safari and chrome

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch" role="navigation" id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas" style="height:200px !important;">
</nav>
```

But it takes height as 888px in firefox

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse navbar-offcanvas navbar-offcanvas-touch" role="navigation" id="js-bootstrap-offcanvas" style="height:888px">
</nav>
```

so how to override it

Comment: That style will probably be added using some sort of js, you will need to find it and stop it or use your stylesheet to override it

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @Pete i have tried using the stylesheet it doesn't override do you know any other alternative solution

Comment: inline css overriding?

Comment: What scripts are you using that set the height of that nav element? usually css via the style property is a giveaway that it is a value set via js. So the script setting the value is calculating the height incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't simulate your situation for testing but I think this might fix your problem or help further diagnose the issue.

Change the inline style with javascript after the document loads and parses.

```
window.onload = function()
{
   window.setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('js-bootstrap-offcanvas').style.height = '200px';
   },100);
};
```

Please tell me what happens. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: why have u used setTimeout function

Comment: Because I was concerned that the code would run before the element finished parsing. I didn't want to risk anything so I set a timeout of a tenth of a sec to make sure that everything is complete.